# System of linear Equations for solving three unknowns

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

Hi guys I have the following system of linear equations as shown below

$$-8y_1  + 5y_2  + 0y_3  = -2.8052$$

$$3y_1  + -8y_2  + 5y_3  = 0.1516$$

$$0y_1 + 3y_2 -8y_3 = -19.8819$$

I decided to use Gauss Jordan elimination method to solve for the variables

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    -8 & 5 & 0 & | & -2.8052 \\
    3 & -8 & 5 & | & 0.1516\\
    0 & 3 & -8 & | & -19.8819\\
    \end{matrix}
$$

I decided to reduce R2 by using the folloiwng operation - R2 -----> $\frac{3}{8}$R1+R2 which givs the following

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    -8 & 5 & 0 & | & -2.8052 \\
    0 & -6.125 & 5 & | & -0.9004\\
    0 & 3 & -8 & | & -19.8819\\
    \end{matrix}
$$

Then to further reduce the R3 -----> $\frac{3}{6.125}R2+R3$

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    -8 & 5 & 0 & | & -2.8052 \\
    0 & -6.125 & 5 & | & -0.9004\\
    0 & 0 & -5.551 & | & -20.3229\\
    \end{matrix}
$$

Solving for $y_1,y_2,y_3$ gives the following

$$-5.551y_3 = -20.3229$$
$$y_3 = 3.6611$$

$$-6.125y_2 = -0.9004 +(-5(3.6611))$$
$$y_2 = 3.1357$$

$$-8y_1 = -2.8052 +(-5(3.1357))$$
$$y_1 = 2.3105$$

Comment: Hi Amir I am checkinh your calculation

Comment: Look at your final equations. Why does $y_2$  end up negative?

Comment: yes guys i looked back at the equations and i have calculated y2 and y3 incorrectly throwing of y solutions however y3 is correcti will make the edits @Aryadeva,@quasi

Comment: $y_3$ looks correct to me Amir

Comment: yes it is my issue or what i did wrong was my calculations for y2 and y3 @Aryadeva i have made the corrections thank you both for looking at it

Comment: $y_2=3.135$ Amir is this what you get ?

Comment: yes i got that $y_2 = 3.1357$ and $y_1 = 2.3105$  @Aryadeva

Comment: Thanks for helping me @Aryadeva have a great night

Comment: And yes $y_1=2.31$ this is correct. Amir now Have a good night too. +1 by the way

Comment: @quasi thanks for helping me as well!